# How can I find broken symlinks

Tags: shell, find, symlink

Is there a way to find all symbolic links that don't point anywere?

```
find ./ -type l
```

will give me all symbolic links, but makes no distinction between links that go somewhere and links that don't.

I'm currently doing:

```
find ./ -type l -exec file {} \; | grep broken
```

But I'm wondering what alternate solutions exist.

Answer (score 527, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest **not** to use `find -L`  for the task (see below for explanation). Here are some other ways to do this:

- If you want to use a "pure `find`" method, and assuming the GNU implementation of `find`, it should rather look like this:

  ```
  find . -xtype l
  ```

  (**`xtype`** is a test performed on a dereferenced link)
- portably (though less efficiently), you can also exec `test -e` from within the `find` command:

  ```
  find . -type l ! -exec test -e {} \; -print
  ```
- Even some `grep` trick could be better (i.e., *safer*) than `find -L`, but not exactly such as presented in the question (which greps in entire output lines, including filenames):

  ```
  find . -type l -exec sh -c 'file -b "$1" | grep -q "^broken"' sh {} \; -print
  ```

The `find -L` trick quoted [by solo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34253/9382) from [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8260/find-broken-symlinks) looks nice and hacky, but it has one very **dangerous pitfall**: All the symlinks are followed. Consider directory with the contents presented below:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 michal users  6 May 15 08:12 link_1 -> nonexistent1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 michal users  6 May 15 08:13 link_2 -> nonexistent2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 michal users  6 May 15 08:13 link_3 -> nonexistent3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 michal users  6 May 15 08:13 link_4 -> nonexistent4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 michal users 11 May 15 08:20 link_out -> /usr/share/
```

If you run `find -L . -type l` in that directory, all `/usr/share/` would be searched as well (and that can take really long)<sup>1</sup>. **For a `find` command that is "immune to outgoing links", don't use `-L`**.

---

<sup>1</sup> This may look like a minor inconvenience (the command will "just" take long to traverse all `/usr/share`) – but can have more severe consequences. For instance, consider chroot environments: They can exist in some subdirectory of the main filesystem and contain symlinks to absolute locations. Those links could seem to be broken for the "outside" system, because they only point to proper places once you've entered the chroot. I also recall that some bootloader used symlinks under `/boot` that only made sense in an initial boot phase, when the boot partition was mounted as `/`.

So if you use a `find -L` command to find and then delete broken symlinks from some harmless-looking directory, you might even break your system...

Comment: This is something I hadn't considered @rozcietrzewiacz and is something that will definitely effect my particular case.  Thanks for the thorough follow-up.

Comment: I think this might be the answer to a major performance problem we've been having with a particular script. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome! I've been writing throw-away Python script for this particular one!! :-/

Comment: I think `-type l` is redundant since `-xtype l` will operate as `-type l` on non-links. So `find -xtype l` is probably all you need. Thanks for this approach.

Comment: @quornian Great catch! Indeed, `find -xtype l` is enough. The only difference is in the number of system calls performed by each command (which indicates `find -type l -xtype l` should be faster). But I guess this would make a difference only on a large filesystem trees.

Comment: I think it is not a good solution to grep for a string here. If you have a different locale, the output is in a different language, and you grep expression will fail.

Comment: I don't understand why `-xtype l` works. `find . -type l -xtype l` means "find all the symlinks to symlinks", rather than, "find all the symlinks to files that don't exist", right?

Comment: Be aware that those solutions don't work for all filesystem types. For example it won't work for checking if `/proc/XXX/exe` link is broken. For this, use `test -e "$(readlink /proc/XXX/exe)"`.

Comment: @Flimm `find . -xtype l` means "find all symlinks whose (ultimate) target files are symlinks". But the ultimate target of a symlink cannot be a symlink, otherwise we can still follow the link and it is not the ultimate target. Since there is no such symlinks, we can define them as something else, i.e. broken symlinks.

Comment: @weakish I would rather say that `-xtype` follows the chain of symbolic links and evaluates the file at the end, which can only be a symbolic link in case it is broken.

Comment: @JoóÁdám "which can only be a symbolic link in case it is broken". Give  "broken symbolic link" or "non exist file" an individual type, instead of overloading `l`, is less confusing to me.

Comment: The warning at the end is useful, but note that this does not apply to the `-L` hack but rather to (blindly) removing broken symlinks in general.

Comment: I somehow suspected that *`-L`* was risky and that's why I found this. On breaking systems from symlinks I recall doing something (but I was able to salvage it because it was an experiment of sort) with *`/dev/null`* years ago. I needn't elaborate on why there was a symlink to it - it was in any case risky; it was not to do with *`find`* but something about recursively following the link nonetheless (or rather in this case dereferencing the link). I have this memory I've played with the same functionality before but I don't know for sure and it's not really important. (1/2)

Comment: As for *`-xtype l`* some comments on the options that change how symlinks in *`find`* go in order to find broken symlinks: (1) Because of how *`-L`* works **don't use that option** for broken symlink tests. (2) *`-P`* is the default and *`-xtype l`* works fine to find broken symlinks. But (3) *`-H`* **appears** to work but I do not know if it has any implications in different circumstances. Thus because what you and the commentator suggest it seems what needs to be done is **only use** *`-xtype l`*. Oh and correct: *`-xtype`* is **not specified in POSIX**. (2/2)

Comment: Another comment. Because the *`-xtype`* isn't available on all systems e.g. macOS the second option, *`find . -type l ! -exec test -e {} \; -print`* seems to me to be the proper answer. However - and maybe this is an artefact of books of old that I read aeons ago - I think it should actually be: *`find . -type l \! -exec test -e '{}' \; -print`*. However if you want to act on each file maybe *`-exec`* is a better idea? Or if you have GNU find then *`-print0 | xargs -0 `* more so.

Comment: @qwertzguy Did you mean to replace `{}` with `"$(readlink /proc/XXX/exe)"` as in `find . -type l ! -exec test -e "$(readlink {})" \; -print` ?

Comment: @Setaa I don't quite remember (been 5 years), but yea I think I was just giving an example with just `test`, to adapt the full `find` command above, what you wrote seems correct.

Comment: Comparing times of `find . -xdev -type l -xtype l` vs. `find . -xdev -xtype l`, I've found that the first test runs about 5 times faster than the last, while giving same results.

Answer (score 57):

As rozcietrzewiacz has already commented, `find -L` can have unexpected consequence of expanding the search into symlinked directories, so isn't the optimal approach.  What no one has mentioned yet is that

```
find /path/to/search -xtype l
```

is the more concise, and logically identical command to

```
find /path/to/search -type l -xtype l
```

None of the solutions presented so far will detect cyclic symlinks, which is another type of breakage.  [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/295929/how-do-i-find-and-report-on-broken-symbolic-links-automatically/433273) addresses portability.  To summarize, the portable way to find broken symbolic links, including cyclic links, is:

```
find /path/to/search -type l -exec test ! -e {} \; -print
```

For more details, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35771/linux-find-and-remove-all-symlinks-relating-to-a-directory) or [ynform.org](http://ynform.org/w/Pub/FindCommandDetectUnixCyclicSymbolicLink).  Of course, the definitive source for all this is the [findutils documentaton](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html).

Comment: Short, consice, and addresses the `find -L` pitfall as well as cyclical links. +1

Comment: Nice. The last one works on MacOSX as well, while @rozcietrzewiacz's answer didn't.

Comment: @neu242 That is likely because *`-xtype`* is not specified in POSIX and indeed if you look at *`find(1)`* in macOS it has *`-type`* but **not** *`-xtype`*.

Comment: `find $HOME -type l -exec test ! -e {} \; -print` prints a lot of 'permission denied' messages, namely from the Waydroid config folder. Fedora 37.

Comment: `find /home/user -type l -exec test ! -e {} \; -print | less` also outputs the (open profile) `lock` files for all Firefox, Thunderbird and Tor browser. Should be left untouched, I can only assume.

Comment: It is giving identical results, but it is not the same in terms of performance. In my tests, it is 2-5 times slower, than if you DO specify `-type l` first.

Answer (score 56):

The `symlinks` command from http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/utils/file/symlinks-1.4.tar.gz can be used to identify symlinks with a variety of characteristics. For instance:

```
$ rm a
$ ln -s a b
$ symlinks .
dangling: /tmp/b -> a
```

Comment: Is this tool available for osx?

Comment: Never mind, got it compiled.

Comment: Apparently `symlinks` is pre-installed on Fedora.

Comment: For cases where the return from said `symlinks` command might be too cluttered, can use `symlinks . | grep dangling` .

Comment: To recurse and filter out matches: `symlinks -r . | grep '^dangling:'`

Comment: ... the `-d` flag removes the dangling links.

Answer (score 9):

If you need a different behavior whether the link is broken or cyclic you can also use %Y with find:

```
$ touch a
$ ln -s a b  # link to existing target
$ ln -s c d  # link to non-existing target
$ ln -s e e  # link to itself
$ find . -type l -exec test ! -e {} \; -printf '%Y %p\n' \
   | while read type link; do
         case "$type" in
         N) echo "do something with broken link $link" ;;
         L) echo "do something with cyclic link $link" ;;
         esac
      done
do something with broken link ./d
do something with cyclic link ./e
```

This example is copied from [this post (site deleted)](http://otomaton.wordpress.com/2012/12/26/find-broken-symbolic-links/).

**Reference**

- [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Comment: Yet another shorthand for those whose `find` command does not support `xtype` can be derived from this: `find . type l -printf "%Y %p\n" | grep -w '^N'`. As andy beat me to it with the same (basic) idea in his script, I was reluctant to write it as separate answer. :)

Answer (score 8):

I believe adding the `-L` flag to your command will allow you do get rid of the `grep`:

```
$ find -L . -type l
```

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8260/find-broken-symlinks

from the manual:

> ##### `-L`
>
> Cause the file information and file type (see `stat`(2)) returned
> for each symbolic link to be those of the file referenced by the
> link, not the link itself. If the referenced file does not exist,
> the file information and type will be for the link itself.

Comment: At first I've upvoted this, but then I've realised how **dangerous** it may be. Before you use it, *please [have a look at my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691/9382)*!

Answer (score 7):

For `zsh` users:

```
rm -v -- **/*(-@)
```

To also remove hidden ones:

```
rm -v -- **/*(D-@)
```

*from [zsh user guide](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html#l141) (search for `broken symlinks`)*

Answer (score 3):

Simple no-brainer answer, which is a variation on OP's version. Sometimes, you just want something easy to type or remember:

```
find . | xargs file | grep -i "broken symbolic link"
```

Or, if you need to handle NULL terminators:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep -i "broken symbolic link"
```

Comment: In similar spirit, you could also do `find . > /dev/null` then just look at the stderr output.

Answer (score 3):

`find . -xtype l` will skip broken links pointing to files in inaccessible directories. You can just search for links to inaccessible files:

```
find . -type l ! -readable
```

This works correctly for cyclic symlinks and is also more efficient than using `-exec test …` with `find` command.

Answer (score 2):

I use this for my case and it works quite well, as I know the directory to look for broken symlinks:

```
find -L $path -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

and my folder does include a link to `/usr/share` but it doesn't traverse it.
Cross-device links and those that are valid for chroots, etc. are still a pitfall but for my use case it's sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`find -L . -type l |xargs symlinks` will give you info whether the link exists or not on a per foundfile basis.

Answer (score 1):

This will print out the names of broken symlinks in the current directory.

```
for l in $(find . -type l); do cd $(dirname $l); if [ ! -e "$(readlink $(basename $l))" ]; then echo $l; fi; cd - > /dev/null; done
```

Works in Bash. Don't know about other shells.

Answer (score 0):

Most comprehensive (imho) command to find broken symlinks without crossing partition bounds. Note, that symlink arguments must be containing directories, not symlinks themselves.

```
find . -xdev -type d \
| stdbuf -oL xargs -d '\n' symlinks \
| stdbuf -oL grep -e '^dangling'
```

Answer (score 0):

I took

```bsh
find ./ -type l -exec file {} \; | that.awk
```

and piped it into an Awk script, that way you can do whatever.

```c
#!/bin/awk -f
# ==============================================================================
BEGIN {
      FS=":"
      w=7
}
# ==============================================================================
{
   sub(/^ /,"",$2)               # remove leading spc
   p=index($2,"to")              # 'to' pointer
   s=substr($2,1,p-2)            # status
   t=substr($2,p+3)              # target

   switch(s)
   {
      case /^broken.*/ :
         printf("\n")
         printf("%"w"s %s\n","target:",t)
         printf("%"w"s %s\n","source:",$1)
         printf("%"w"s %s\n","status:",s)
         break
#      default:
#         printf("\n")
#         printf("%"w"s %s\n","target:",t)
   }
}
# ==============================================================================
END {
}
# ==============================================================================
# functions
# ==============================================================================
```