# Linux find and remove all symlinks relating to a directory

Tags: symlink

So, I have a bit of a situation where I created many symlinks in an attempt to get them to work, trying all sorts of combinations .. now I have this error:

```
ls: cannot access /etc/sv/me: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

There is no symlinks in /service/ or /etc/sv/ 
The only way I can find to solve this error is to remove all of the symlinks relating to /service/ or /etc/sv/ but i don't even see the symlinks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can identify cyclic symlinks with a bit of `find` trickery, try this:

```
find /path/to/search -type l -a ! \( -xtype b -o -xtype c -o -xtype d -o -xtype p -o -xtype f -o -xtype s -o -xtype l \) 2>/dev/null
```

This works by filtering for symlinks, then excluding anything where the type of the symlink's target is any of the possible inode types. The only things are left are those where `find` can't determine the type of the target, which only happens for cyclic symlinks (broken ones match `-xtype l`)

Comment: Ah, awesome, ty :)

Comment: I have to admit, I was quite pleased when I discovered that one :-)

Answer (score 2):

Symlinks do not exhibit "action at a distance" -- being the target of a symlink never affects the target directly.

The error you're seeing indicates that either `/etc`, or `/etc/sv`, or `/etc/sv/me` is a symlink. Figure out which one it is and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using lower case `-l` (dash ell) instead of upper case `-L` when doing `ls`.