# list all symbolic links to valid directories only with find

Tags: find, directory, symlink

I can use

```
find /search/location -type l
```

to list all symbolic links inside */search/location*.

How do I limit the output of `find` to symbolic links that refer to a valid directory, and exclude both, broken symbolic links and links to files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU find (the implementation on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin):

```
find /search/location -type l -xtype d
```

With find implementations that lack the `-xtype` primary, you can use two invocations of `find`, one to filter symbolic links and one to filter the ones that point to directories:

```
find /search/location -type l -exec sh -c 'find -L "$@" -type d -print' _ {} +
```

or you can call the `test` program:

```
find /search/location -type l -exec test {} \; -print
```

Alternatively, if you have zsh, it's just a matter of two [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (`@` = is a symbolic link, `-` = the following qualifiers act on the link target, `/` = is a directory):

```
print -lr /search/location/**/*(@-/)
```

Comment: `find . -type l -exec sh -c 'find "$@" -L -type d -print' _ {} +` yielded `find: unknown predicate \`-L'` for me. moving the `-L` in the second find invocation before the `"$@"` made this work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find /search/location -type l -exec test -e {} \; -print
```

From `man test`:

> ```
>    -e FILE
>           FILE exists
> ```

You might also benefit from [this U&L answer to How can I find broken symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691/4252); be sure to read the comments too.

**Edit**: `test -d` to check if "FILE exists and is a directory"

```
find /search/location -type l -exec test -d {} \; -print
```

Comment: thank you, but this finds links to files as well

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
for i in $(find /search/location -type l); do 
  test -d $(readlink $i) && echo $i 
done
```

Comment: Don't parse the output of `find`. This breaks on file names containing whitespace or wildcard characters. For the same reason, put double quotes around variable substitutions. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters?s=2|1.2316