# How to grep stderr?

Tags: grep, pipe, stderr

<strike>How do I grep this command that includes a wildcard?</strike>

How do I grep *stderr*?

The grep does not seem to do anything:

```
$ less /Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/* | grep "Not a file"
/Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle is a directory
/Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/wunderline is a directory
/Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/yo is a directory
```

This is a very hacky use of less, and probably worthy of another question, but my intention is to find broken symlinks in this directory. It happens to be that less will print `is a directory` if it is valid and `Not a file or directory` if it is invalid. I believe it is worth asking anyway as this is indicative of my lack of understanding of <strike>wildcard operators</strike> stderr.

Comment: Clarified intention in OP.

Comment: You have a valid point! I didn't ask the question directly. I would like to defend myself by saying that many quirky situations offer learning opportunities. In this case, I felt like it was an opportunity to learn more about the interaction between wildcards and grep.

Comment: `less ... 2>&1 | grep yo`

Comment: @SatoKatsura That works! Thank you. You can provide it as an answer and I will accept it, or I can do it. I small explanation of why that works would be great, too.

Comment: I am guessing that it directs stderr to stdout, which is what grep uses?

Comment: Yes, you want to `grep` the error messages from `less`, and `less` prints error messages to `stderr`.

Comment: See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691/117516) for a better way to find broken symlinks.

Comment: Since we're talking about odd ways of doing things, `cat` might be easier...  `cat * > /dev/null` will send the results to stderr.  If you want to catch it in a variable, `badlines=$(cat * 2>&1 >/dev/null) ; echo "$badlines"`

Answer (score 2):

The wildcard has nothing to do with `grep`, all that `grep` sees is what is piped to it. The wildcard is expanded by the shell and the list of files it expands to is passed to `less`. So the issue has nothing at all to do with `grep`.

That said, if you're looking for broken links, you can do:

```
for f in /Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/*; do
     [ -e $(readlink -f "$f") ] || echo "$f"; 
done
```

That will iterate over all files and directories in `/Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/`, check if their  target exists (`readlink` will print the file name iot was run on if that file isn't a link) and print the name if it doesn't.

---

A much better solution I [just learned about](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691/22222) is:

```
find /Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/ -xtype l
```

The `-xtype` will test whether the target of the link is, in this case, a link, so it will only be true for dangling links.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the OP to reflect the real question now that I understand it. Your answer is helpful, though I will go with `2>&1` as the accepted answer since it clears up my fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: @Raine in that case, please post the answer yourself and accept it so the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: `find -L /Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/ -type l`

Comment: @Costas `find -xtype l` is safer for reasons explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691/22222).

Comment: I see now. Thanks. So for such security reason we have to add `-path '/Users/raine/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/*'`

Comment: @Costas I guess so yes, I'm only learning about all this now myself. I think using `-xtype l` is much simpler though. As long as your `find` supports it, it's not POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

As @SatoKatsura pointed out in their comment, the (hacky) use of `less` is outputting to `stderr`, while grep reads from `stdout`. Though it is a poor solution to the actual task of finding dead symlinks, it can work by redirecting `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
less ~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/* 2>&1 | grep "Not a file"
```