# What purpose does the minus (-) in `find -! -exec` serve?

Tags: find

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691/42515), what is the use of `-!` in `find`?

Consider the following code:

```
find . -type l -! -exec test -e {} \; -print
```

This alternative seems to do the same exact thing:

```
find . -type l ! -exec test -e {} \; -print
```

It appears the `-!` works like `!`, meaning negation of the following expression. Which makes sense. But why not just `!` then? I can't seem to find any documentation on such syntax.

Comment: I think it's a mistake (and generous interpretation by, I presume, GNU `find`).

Comment: It is certainly _not_ the case for the `find` in NetBSD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accepting `-!` in addition to the standard `!` (and likewise for other punctuation operators: `(`, `)`, and the GNU-specific `,`) is a quirk of the command line parser of GNU find. The code just happens to be slightly easier to write if it doesn't reject `-!` and the like as ill-formed. Since `-!` would otherwise be an error, there's no harm in accepting it. The POSIX standard doesn't say anything about what `-!` means: as far as the standard is concerned, it's an implementation-defined predicate, which implementations are free to use to  mean whatever they want.

Here's an overview of how the code in GNU find works:

- The parser code contains a [list of operators](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/parser.c?h=v4.6.0&id=992a6b62ab8061531dc0ad40325b8e4c222fce66#n226). Operators are stored without their leading `-`, to make the code slightly smaller and faster.
- The [command line parser](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/tree.c?h=v4.6.0&id=992a6b62ab8061531dc0ad40325b8e4c222fce66#n1268) calls [`looks_like_expression`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/util.c?h=v4.6.0&id=992a6b62ab8061531dc0ad40325b8e4c222fce66#n770) to determine whether an argument looks like a predicate. Predicates begin with `-`, except for the single-punctuation-character operators.
- Once the predicate has been determined, [`find_parser`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/parser.c?h=v4.6.0&id=992a6b62ab8061531dc0ad40325b8e4c222fce66#n641) ignored the leading `-` if there is one. This is the point where the distinction between `!` and `-!` is lost.

`looks_like_expression` or `find_parser` could reject `-` followed by a punctuation character. But either way it would require additional code for no real benefit.

Comment: Wow, good one. That's kind of what I expected. Certainly kudos for digging that up and explaining in detail, though.

Answer (score -1):

The -! is negagting the expression "-type l" which means in your example "List all entries which are not a link".

-type l will become only true, if the "file" is a link, -! will negate it.

From find manpage:

```
The POSIX standard specifies parentheses `(', `)', negation `!' and the `and' and `or' operators ( -a, -o).
```

The minus is the seperator for the options. Like in any other command, every option is seperated by a minus (e.g. ls -l). It is not reversing the meaning of the Exclamation mark (!).

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question. The OP knows about `!` and they are asking why `-!` is also valid given that it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: This isn't even right: `!` negates the following expression, not the preceding one.