# Is there a tool to auto delete all invalid symbolic links?

Tags: filesystems, symlink

I have a Fedora workstation, when upgrade the system some software for example LibreOffice do not delete its old symbol link in `/usr/bin` and when I update other software, there are a lot of warnings due to that. And in other situations, there are also this kind of problems. Is there a efficient console application to scan and automatically delete all these links whose target doesn't exist?

Open source is better. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FSlint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) will do this for you, at least in its GUI. It also has command-line variants:

```
/usr/share/fslint/fslint/findbl /usr/bin
```

but that doesn’t appear to have an option to delete the broken links.

However, you don’t even need a *specific* tool for this, your system already has a tool which is capable of deleting broken symlinks: `find`. See [How can I find broken symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34248/86440) for details; you can take a `find` command given there and add `-delete` to it to delete the links (after checking the output...):

```
find /usr/bin -xtype l -delete
```