# Why does the test command apparently choke on a for loop variable?

Tags: bash, for, test

I want to determine all broken symlinks within a directory.

In ignorance of a better solution, I tried this simple bash one-liner (bash version is 4.2.46, which may be worth mentioning because it's a bit dated):

```bash
for f in $(ls); do test -L "$f" || continue; test -e "$f" || echo "$f deadlink"; done
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I tried nailing down the error and if I run this

```bash
for f in $(ls); do test -L $f && echo "$f is a valid symlink"; done
```

no output is produced, despite existing and valid symlinks. If I run the same command with `$f` replaced with the actual file name, it works. Also `f=filename; test -L $f && echo "$f is a valid symlink";` works as expected, so the problem seems to be the loop.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem comes from `ls`’s use of colours in its output. Since you’re [parsing `ls`’s output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440), if `ls` outputs colours, the corresponding escape codes will end up in the values given to `f`, and `test` will fail to find a matching file. Since `test` fails the test without any output in such cases, you wouldn’t be any the wiser.

Use a glob instead:

```
for f in *; do test -L "$f" || continue; test -e "$f" || echo "$f deadlink"; done
```

See [How can I find broken symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34248/86440) for other possible solutions to your underlying problem.

Comment: Indeed the colors are a problem. If I replace `$(ls)` with `$(ls --color=never)`, it works as well (alternatively: `$(\ls)` to avoid alias expansion). Thanks for the idea of using a simple glob as well. Question answered.